# C# Xamarin Exit function

Tags: c#, function, xamarin, exit

I have an if statement where I want to abort the next steps and start over. But how can I use a Exit; (like PHP) or something like that?
This is my code:

```
if (SelectedQuantity != null | SelectedProduct != null)
{
    string toast = string.Format("You may only fill 1 of the input fields!");
    Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

After the "if", it puts values in the database, but I want to abort that process if you get in the if statement. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You should really understand the basics of c# before attempting to play with a behemoth like Xamarin. The Microsoft Docs site is a very good place to get started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on the context, but generally you can just use `return` to exit the method at any given point

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not really expressive (we don't know what surrounds it). But I would tell you to use the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you're if statement is directly within a method you use the `return` keyword to end the method early (unless the method is a function and returning a value then you `return someValue`. If you're in a loop you skip over and continue the loop with the `continue` keyword, you break out of the loop with the `break` keyword. Also, and I apologize for this, but I recommend taking the extra time to learn C# first because this is very basic; not to mention your or operation in the if statement isn't shorted `||` and you're string.format is better as a string literal.

Although this isn't part of your question; I did see someone make a comment and you ignored it with a little sarcasm (although their comment was sarcasm).  In defense it's because this is C# elementary knowledge.

Anyway, I'm going to take a little time to explain it and if you appreciate the knowledge maybe it will inspire you to dig more into the C# language to do things more or less the right way.

As for using `string.format` this should be used only to actually format strings; which it's good at.  However; when you just have a string literal (characters in quotes that are technically constant), then string.format should be avoided.  Here is the IL generated code for two tiny one line apps I made to demonstrate only the different between string.format and using a string literal when it can be done.

**App using string literal.**

```
namespace StringFormatVSStringLiteral
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var value = "My name is Michael";
        }
    }
}
```

**IL Generated**

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] string 'value')
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "My name is Michael"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

**App using string.Format**

```
namespace StringFormatVSStringLiteral
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var value = string.Format("My name is Michael");
        }
    }
}
```

**IL Generated**

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       18 (0x12)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] string 'value')
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "My name is Michael"
  IL_0006:  call       !!0[] [mscorlib]System.Array::Empty<object>()
  IL_000b:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                              object[])
  IL_0010:  stloc.0
  IL_0011:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

So you can see in using string.Format should be avoided when possible only because it increased the stack and calls.  If you were to have this, say in a loop, or a resource intensive application the difference might be critical.

As for the or operator; in C# you can short circtuit or `|` by doubling it `||`.  What this does is test the first value; in an or operator if the first test succeeds it skips testing the second step; which is faster obviously.  When you write the operator as `|` you force it to test each value whether the first finalizes the operation or not.  Also note that the second or operator `|` is used for binary operations and flags in C# because of the way it works internally.  The and operator is the same where `&` tests both sides even if the first one fails; which can and should be short circuited using `&&`.  The same thing applies to the `&` operator where it is used for binary operations as well as adjusting flags.